# Save the value from Multiline Textbox into SQL Server with line brea

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, textbox, multiline

I got one multiline textbox call txtDesc.
The user can key in multiline value such as :

```
Hai.
I'm robot.
Please feed me.
```

I want to save into database with the line break and will display it back later as user key in.

if i save the value as below code, the line break will not save.

```
dim strDesc as string = txtDesc.text
```

how to make this happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got the answer :

To save from multiline textbox to database :

```
  Dim strDesc As String
  strDesc = ReplaceNewLines(txtDesc.Text, True)
```

To show back from database to multiline textbox :

```
strDesc = productDetails.ProductDesc.Replace("<br/>", vbCrLf)
txtDesc.Text = strDesc
```

Answer (score 0):

Love the sample text :)

How are you saving and loading this to/from SQL ? If I have a multiline textbox, the `.Text` property includes the line break character -

```
"Hai.\n\I'm robot.\n\Please feed me."
```

I save this into an NVARCHAR(MAX) field in a table in SQL, and when I load it back into the textbox, I get the line breaks exactly as it was typed in.

Can you post your your load/save code ?

Comment: why do ask me for load/save code? my question to get that code. i want to know how to save that value from multiline textbox into sql server. thank you.

Comment: I'm asking, because I have the exact same scenario in a number of web applications I have built, and when I load content into a multi-line textbox the line breaks appear correctly.

Comment: I am using nHibernate to persist data; what are you using ?