# Convert linebreaks from multiline textbox value stored in MS SQL Server to HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, line-breaks

Ok, I'm storing the value of a multiline textbox in SQL Server in column [txt] of type nvarchar(1000).

The multiline text in this case is:

> Dear sir,
>
> Welcome to our platform.
>
> Best, Us

After saving the results to MSSQL I run a query to select the values.
When I copy the value of column [txt] directly from the query results in SQL Server Management Studio and paste this into Notepad++, I see the original text again.
Also the loading the text again from the database and assigning that to the multiline textbox is working fine.

However, when in my code behind I assign the value of database column [txt] to a string variable (so not from Textbox to the variable):

```
Dim mailContent as String = row.txt
```

and then send this value in an email, the email recipient sees the text without the line breaks, so:

> Dear sir, Welcome to our platform. Best, Us

I tried all different scenerios below:

```
Dim registryTA As New registryTableAdapters.registryTableAdapter
Dim registryDT As registry.registryDataTable = registryTA.GetDataByUserid(_userid)
Dim mailcontent As String

mailcontent = registryDT(0).invitetext.Replace(vbLf, "<br/>").Replace(vbCrLf, "<br/>")

mailContent = mailContent.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")
mailContent = mailContent.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>")
mailContent = Server.HTMLEncode(mailContent)
mailContent = Server.HTMLDecode(mailContent)
mailContent = mailContent.Replace(vbCrlf, "<br/>")
```

Preferably I don't want to alter the way I store or retrieve the data in/from MSSQL (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536431/save-the-value-from-multiline-textbox-into-sql-server-with-line-brea)), so how can I convert the current value of [txt] to HTML format and get the linebreaks?

Comment: Please show how you retrieve `row` how you initialize `mailContent`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've added some extra code demonstrating this. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the text might only have `\n` in your content. Try replacing `\n` with `</br>` as well. Try this,

```
mailContent = mailContent.Replace(vbLF, "<br/>").Replace(vbCrlf, "<br/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace line breaks in SQL select query

```
 REPLACE(Account.AcAddress,CHAR(10),'<br/>')
```